# On click should not work on child

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried few solutions available in here. I have added those code in JS as comments.
My code, please review. 
I am trying to achieve: 
Checkbox should not be checked when I click on "more info". Others are working fine.

```js
$('.is-monogram label').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  $('.main-wrapper').slideDown('slow');
  alert('clicked the foobar');
});



/*  $(".is-monogram label").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
 });  */

/* var a = $('.is-monogram .option');
a.on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  $('.main-wrapper').slideDown('slow');
  alert( 'clicked the foobar' );
}); 


a.on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
}); */
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="is-monogram">
  <div class="testing">
    <div class="testing-one">
      <input type="checkbox" id="id_one" name="name_one" value="1" class="class_one">

      <label class="option" for="id_one">Lorem Ipsum Lorem
 <span class="parent-span">
  <span class="parent-child-span">more info</span>
  </span> 
  </label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main-wrapper">
  Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla quis lorem ut
  libero malesuada feugiat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis
  ac lectus.
</div>
```

Comment: Does the "more info" -span need to be inside the label?

Comment: I would move it outside, it has nothing to do with the actual input and therefore shouldn't be part of the label

Comment: @esko. Yes, I don't have control over the html structure. Otherwise, I would have moved it outside.

Comment: Can you wrap the text like this `<p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem</p>`?

Comment: @Pavel, no I can't since it is coming dynamically from Drupal.

Comment: `if(e.target.classList.contains("parent-child-span")) return e.preventDefault();`  as the first line.

Comment: why not just bind the slide down click to the parent-child-span if that's all you want to target?

Comment: Hmm in your example the main-wrapper ***does not*** show if you click "more info" was that not what you wanted? I'm confused.

Comment: @Esko  I believe he wants to prevent the checkbox been selected if you click `more info`

Comment: @esko, correct. But when I click on "More info", checkbox is checked which should not happen.

Comment: @Kumar You don't mention that anywhere in your question, please edit that information in.

Comment: @Esko `when I click on input/label, not when I click on "more info"`

Comment: @Keith ***Main-wrapper div should show only*** when I click on input/label... Nothing about the checkbox

Comment: @Kumar  Have you tried my suggestion yet, as that will do exactly that.  Esko I think I must have filled in the gaps after running the snippet.. :)

Comment: Use @Keith's code or just `if (e.target !== this) { e.preventDefault(); return; }`

Comment: @Keith. Your code is working. You can answer on this thread, I will mark as close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you most likely looking for here is `preventDefault`,..

So what we can do is check to see if the actual element we clicked has the class `parent-child-span`, if it does then we prevent the default action, that would cause the checkbox to be triggered.

So placing the below as the first line will do this.

```
if(e.target.classList.contains("parent-child-span")) return e.preventDefault();
```

eg..

```js
$('.is-monogram label').on('click', function(e) {
  //add this line below.
  if(e.target.classList.contains("parent-child-span")) 
    return e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  $('.main-wrapper').slideDown('slow');
  alert('clicked the foobar');
});



/*  $(".is-monogram label").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
 });  */

/* var a = $('.is-monogram .option');
a.on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  $('.main-wrapper').slideDown('slow');
  alert( 'clicked the foobar' );
}); 


a.on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
}); */
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="is-monogram">
  <div class="testing">
    <div class="testing-one">
      <input type="checkbox" id="id_one" name="name_one" value="1" class="class_one">

      <label class="option" for="id_one">Lorem Ipsum Lorem
 <span class="parent-span">
  <span class="parent-child-span">more info</span>
  </span> 
  </label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main-wrapper">
  Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla quis lorem ut
  libero malesuada feugiat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis
  ac lectus.
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want me to add your code?
jQuery('.is-monogram label').click(function () {
if(e.target.classList.contains("parent-child-span")) 
    return e.preventDefault();
  var btndisabled = jQuery('.add-to-bag-section input[type=submit]').is(":disabled");
  if (this.checked) {
    if (!btndisabled) {
      jQuery('.add-to-bag-section input[type=text], .add-to-bag-section input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    jQuery('.monogram-custom-wrapper, .monogram-color').slideDown('slow');

This is how my actual code looks.

Comment: I've placed it in the snippet,.. I'll put a comment in there to make it more obvious.   Doing like others have said you can just put `e.preventDefault` in your check,.  But I'm been more specific in only excluding if it's `parent-child-span` in case you later add any more elements.

Comment: @Kumar  What you have just posted above, looks correct to me.

Answer (score 1):

You are already handling the case where the user clicked on the `span` with your `if (e.target !== this)` check.

Just add `e.preventDefault()` in there to stop it.

```
  if (e.target !== this){
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
```

---

Edited snippet

```js
$('.is-monogram label').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this){
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
    }
  $('.main-wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
});





/*  $(".is-monogram label").on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
 });  */

/* var a = $('.is-monogram .option');
a.on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target !== this)
    return;
  $('.main-wrapper').slideDown('slow');
  alert( 'clicked the foobar' );
}); 


a.on("click", function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert( "I was clicked, but my parent will not be." );
}); */
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="is-monogram">
  <div class="testing">
    <div class="testing-one">
      <input type="checkbox" id="id_one" name="name_one" value="1" class="class_one">

      <label class="option" for="id_one">Lorem Ipsum Lorem
 <span class="parent-span">
  <span class="parent-child-span">more info</span>
  </span> 
  </label>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main-wrapper">
  Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla quis lorem ut
  libero malesuada feugiat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis
  ac lectus.
</div>
```